# Catching OperationalError 1040 in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, web

I run my Django website on a shared server and so from time to time my users get an Internal Server Error 500 page due to the specific OperationalError Exception identifying itself as `(1040, "Too Many Connections")`. I have a custom 500.html page and `handler500 = 'myapp.views.error500'` in my `urls.py` -- the `error500` method in my view is:

```
def error500(request):
    exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
    msg = ''
    if exctype == OperationalError:
        msg = 'We\'re busy at the moment -- please reload this page in a little while.'
    return render_to_response('500.html', {'msg': msg})
```

where I import `OperationalError` from the `MySQLdb` module. But this will attribute all MySQL errors to "Too Many Connections" -- how can I catch just the 1040 error? And how can I test it without waiting to see if the shared MySQL server gets overloaded whilst I happen to be browsing my own site?

Answer (score -1):

Here's what worked for me:

```
def error500(request):
    exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
    msg = ''
    if exctype == OperationalError and value.args[0] == 1040:
        msg = 'We\'re busy at the moment -- please reload this page in a little while.'
    return render_to_response('500.html', {'msg': msg})
```

I tested it by writing a bash script to open up 151 connections (the maximum) to my MySQL server and then visited my page to attempt opening up the 152nd...